# IBM Worklight Failing to start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

**Configuration**: Eclipse (Juno) 4.2.2

**IBM Worklight version**: 6.2.0.01

**Java version:**
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

**JDK**: jdk1.7.0_71.jdk

**Java Compiler**: 1.7

My worklight studio was previously working and suddenly stops working after I had to force quit my eclipse. Even after reinstallation of the plugins, the error still recurs.

Here's a screenshot of the initial error log before 'Worklight server failed to start' and 'Failed to deploy application in the worklight server'. Any help to fix this issue will be deeply appreciated. Worklight studio issues like this is starting to get frustrating.

[image]

Comment: Close eclipse, Try to delete "Worklight Development Server" folder from your workspace, and Start Eclipse and Worklight Development Server

Comment: I have done the same n number of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled java from my mac. Reinstalled Java (JDK & JRE), new Eclipse (Juno 4.2.2) -> Then installed IBM Worklight Studio plugin. Figured it was the problem with Java as it was throwing the java exception 'unable to read the manifest'. Probably there was some issue after updating to Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

It looks Java EE got corrupted somehow,

So as suggested the best approach would be to use a fresh Eclipse instance with a new plug-in installation and a new workspace as well. This way it makes sure everything is fresh and new.

Comment: Yes, that usually resolves the issues. But i already tried it many times

Comment: Then use a new eclipse instance altogether.

Comment: I tried that too. Since i am used to seeing such issues, i kept a backup of eclipse after first installation of worklight studio.

Comment: Remove your project from the workspace, create a new project. Does it work?

Comment: You did not do one of the above then. Use a NEW eclipse installation, not backup. New download - new zip. New workspace, new plugin install.

Comment: Fair enough, but that's not a solution, right ?? There should be a more elegant way to fix the issue. I am sure, i will run into this again and i will have to do this whole process again.

Comment: Without a recreation I can't help you but just get you working again.

Comment: Great, thanks. So the Worklight plugin is just not flexible enough.

Comment: Arun, I  am not here to convince you one way or another. I am saying that without a recreation this is difficult to debug, which makes sense.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, and I really appreciate your help. I was just expressing my thoughts on the Worklight Studio - Just hoping that the Worklight Developer team sees such genuine issues from developers and try to make it better in the next revision. Thats all that I intend here as I have to work on Worklight for a while neverthless.

Comment: Did you try deleting just the Worklightserverconfig folder in the workspace? Or just the .war file?

Comment: I first deleted the Worklight server from the servers view. Then i deleted the Worklightserverconfig folder itself. Restarted eclipse, so that it auto generates again. After that I made a new project (Hello world). And that fails to deploy in the server.

Comment: try Eclipse Kepler Service.i had the same problem,i solved by install kepler.

Comment: I installed Kepler and still no luck. It's quite strange, something else other than eclipse and worklight seems to be the problem.

Comment: I tried a new eclipse, new workspace everything. Its really weird

Comment: Reinstalled java, new eclipse, new workspace. Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to set correct IP for Worklight server. It doesn't work with "localhost" or "*".